# rails named_scope as an extension to AR::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope, extending-classes

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :recent, lambda { { :conditions => ['created_at > ?', 1.week.ago] } }
end
```

I want to extend the AR::Base class to have this named_scope for all models, how I can do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new initializer file in **config/initializers** and then re-open ActiveRecord's `Base` class to add the named scope:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    named_scope :recent, lambda {
      { :conditions => ['created_at > ?', 1.week.ago] }
    } 
  end
end
```

—Of course you get a rather ugly error should you attempt to use this named scope on a model that doesn't have a `created_at` attribute...